# Как в label tkinter выводить latex из sympy

Tags: python, tkinter, label, sympy

Мне нужно придумать как в gui написанном на tkinter выводить в label результат вычислений из библиотеки sympy. То есть есть функция вывода текста в label после нажатия на кнопку. Но проблема в том, что я не могу понять как можно выполнять функционал sympy внутри цикла tkinter.

Comment: Что значит "выполнять функционал sympy внутри цикла tkinter"? Добавьте пример кода, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: Имеется в виду что есть label в который должна выводиться формула с генерированная sympy (программа должна рандомно генерировать примеры по заданным критериям. Например квадратное уравнение)

Comment: В общем, пока я вижу решение через matplotlib, он умеет latex отображать. В общем нужно найти примеры latex+matplotlib и matplotlib+tkinter и совместить.